# How to Combine Similar Values Into a Single Column in a Advanced Find in CRM 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I currently have a view on the Queue entity, that includes a Category attribute for an Email, Phone Call, and Appointment:
[image: Advanced Find]

The Category attribute in all entities is a lookup to the same Category Entity Type.

I want to be able to combine them all in a single column on the view:

[image: Advanced Find One Column]

The current only way I can think of, is to create a dummy Category Field on the Queue, and write a plugin to sync it with the category of the activity, or write a plugin on the retrieve multiple that hydrates the column.  Are there any other possibilities?  Also, the business is asking to do this in lots of different situations, so if there is a more "meta" way of handling it, that would be great to.

This is an IFD CRM if it matters.

Comment: the "meta" way will be to create an entity that will hold the source and target columns for the retrieve multiple plugin. but personally I don't like to attach plugins to the retrieve/retrieve multiple messages. in the other hand you can still use the custom entity I described before to be used for the create/update/delete plugins, I realized something similar for the activityparty attributes required for a fetchxml report

Comment: Retrieve plugin is good, just make it fill a *dedicated* field which you'll have to make sure never gets written. Works perfectly for string data, never attempted for lookups. Watch out for the inevitable performance hit.

Comment: @GuidoPreite "the custom entity I described before" ?

Comment: "create an entity that will hold the source and target columns" this I was referring